# Interesting behaviour of the same function in a .js and a .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Hey I've faced some curious and unexpected behavior within my `.js.erb` file. The relevant code and snippets are given for a quick read to help understand the problem.

`orders_controller` Only partial snippet of the function advanced_search

```
def advanced_search
  @filters = params[:filters] || {}
  @is_ajax_search = true

  if @filters.present?
    response = RestClient.post "my_url/orders/" +@filters.to_json      
    @orders = JSON.parse response.body
    logger.debug [params[:offset], params[:limit], @orders["total"]]
    limit = params[:limit] = 50

    @orders["order_items"] = @orders["order_items"].paginate(
      :page => params[:page],
      :per_page => limit,
      :total_entries=>@orders["total"]
    )

    @title = "Advanced Search"
    render
  end
end
```

`orders/advanced_search.html.erb`

```
<%# debug @orders %>
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'advanced_search_oms',  %>
<% end %>
<%= render "advanced_search_orders_form" %>
<div id="advanced_search_orders_table" class="fk-table ajax">
  <%= render "advanced_search_orders_table" %>
</div>
```

`orders/_advanced_search_orders_table`

```
<%= will_paginate @orders["order_items"] %>
```

`javascripts/advanced_search_oms`

```
$(function () {
  $('.pagination a').click(function () {
    alert("The url will no longer change")
    return false;
  });
});
```

But I actually want to define this function in `advanced_search.js.erb`, as I need to use instance variables.

`orders/advanced_search.js.erb`

```
alert("Hello") //Works when a page link is clicked using the will paginate. But is not displayed when the page is loaded. I wonder why?
$(function () {
  alert("Dom is loaded") //Woks like previous alert. Only on page click.
  $('.pagination a').click(function () {
    alert("The url shouldn't change") //But it does. NO ALERT BOX even pops up. It's as if the function doesn't exist.
    <%= logger.info "Entered js" %> //But this worked
    return false;
  });
});
```

Can you help me understand why this happens, and how should I re-define this function?

Comment: Where is `advanced_search.js.erb` located?

Comment: @IlyaKhokhryakov - Just replied. Note the controller is orders.

Comment: How is the .js.erb code getting into the client browser?  where is it rendered in?

Comment: In the controller, orders, I have defined a function advanced_search. In which I just do 'render'. So it renders both advanced_search.html.erb, and also advanced_search.js.erb.

Comment: try `<% logger.info "Entered js" %>` instead of `<%= logger.info "Entered js" %>`